# how to solve $\,-a{y}^2(t) + by(t) -c\,\dfrac{dy}{dt} = K$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
-a{y}^2(t) + by(t) -c\,\frac{dy}{dt} = K
$$

It is a separable first order nonlinear equation, however I have no recall on how to proceed with that...

Is it correct to multiply both members by $\,dt$?

$$-a\,{y}^2(t)\,dt + b\,y(t)\,dt -c\,dy = K\,dt$$

And then perform integration to obtain:

$$-\frac{a}{3}\,{y}^3(t)\,dt + \frac{b}{2}\,{y}^2(t) -c\,y(t) = K\,t$$

Provided the steps above are valid...How to proceed now?

Thanks for your help,

Michele

**EDIT**

Just to summarize what I gathered so far:

First off, as pointed out by @Chinny84, it is incorrect to multiply

$$-a{y}^2(t) + by(t) -c\,\frac{dy}{dt} = K$$

by $dt$ and carry from there. The basic theory (thanks to @Did to point that out) says that:

$$y'(t)=G(y(t)) \leftrightarrow \int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{du}{G(u)}=t $$

Applying this to the equation above means to write:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = - \frac{a{y}^2(t) - by(t) +K}{c} \rightarrow \frac{dy}{a{y}^2(t) - by(t) +K} = -\frac{dt}{c}$$

This is the form one can then integrate:

$$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{du}{a{u}^2(t) - bu(t) +K}= -\int_{0}^{t}\frac{dt}{c}$$

The integral on the LHS is known, one could find it in [this table](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf)

So that the expression evaluates to:

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}} \left\{\arctan(\frac{2ay(t)-b}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}) - \arctan(\frac{2ay(0)-b}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}) \right\} = -\frac{t}{c}$$

Then - provided I did not lose pieces around - finding a neat expression for $y(t)$ gets cumbersome, because of the presence of the $y(0)$ term in the expression.

How is one supposed to deal with the addittive term on LHS?

I see two options, i.e. express

$$\arctan(a) + \arctan(b) = \frac{\arctan(a+b)}{1-ab}$$

and end up with a large expression like:

$$ \arctan(F(y)) = -\frac{t}{c} $$

and work it out from there, or otherwise move the $\arctan(y(0))$ on the RHS and then manipulate after applying the $\tan(.)$ to both sides.

Choosing for the latter option:

$$ \frac{2ay(t)-b}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}} = \tan \left[\arctan \left( \frac{2ay(0)-b}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}\right) -\frac{t\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}{2c} \right]$$

and further:

$$ y(t)= \frac{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}{2a} \, \tan \left[\arctan \left( \frac{2ay(0)-b}{\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}\right) -\frac{t\sqrt{4aK-b^2}}{2c} \right] + \frac{b}{2a} $$

which is giving correctly:

$$ y(t)|_{t=0} = y(0) $$

At this point, I do not dear to use:

$$ \tan(a+b) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{1-\tan(a) \tan(b)} $$

As one would end up with an expression carrying $\tan(t)$ on both numerator and denominator.

- Can anyone check whether the development is correct?
- Also, is there any *clever* or standard way to deal with $\tan(y(t) + \alpha)$ kind of expressions? One just leaves the phase shift?
- I am very curious to see whether this is mathematically correct, as the problem this math should model could not allow for a function like $ \tan(t)$, which is indefinitely growing for a finite $t$.

So probably in the end I have made some mistake :)

Thanks all for your help!!

Michele

Comment: Basics of the theory: if $y'(t)=G(y(t))$ then $dy=G(y)dt$ hence, for every $t$, $$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{du}{G(u)}=t.$$ Simply apply this.

Comment: Thanks Did, I would lie if I told you I was able to act on your input, however I understand this is the correct form to put it.

Comment: What prevented you to "act on my input" (whatever that means)? Please be specific.

Comment: Given the mistake I was doing, I was unable to recognize $(G(y(t))$ as the whole expression. Just to be clear, it is /my/ issue, not yours.
"act on your input" means: understand my mistake and correct it, arriving to the form Chinny84 put it into.

Comment: I think the solution you have right now looks OK (I hope I did not mis a detail somewhere). Just a question, do you know anything about the sign of $4aK-b^2$, since it might change the situation slightly if it is negative (it might be better to use hyperbolic functions in that case)?

Comment: Thanks @mickep, actually this is what I am looking at right now. It is a bit of a "side project" so I can work on it in bits and pieces only.
The underlying problem is the charge of a capacitor through a nonlinear resistor, one whose $i(v)$ characteristic is in the form:
$$ i(v) = \beta \left[ \alpha v - \frac{v^2}{2} \right] $$

Answer (score 1):

First issue you can not integrate the ODE as you have done i.e.
$$
\int -ay^2 +by-c\frac{dy}{dt} dt \neq -\frac{a}{3}y^3+\frac{b}{2}y^2 -cy
$$
Instead you have to do as Did said re-arrange the ODE to have $y$'s on the one side i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{ay^2-by+K}\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{1}{c}
$$

Comment: Thanks Chinny84, having done the algebra explicitly helped me to understand the more concise form in which Did put it. I guess I'll have to rebrush my integrals then :)